# Can I launch a gazebo classic project in gazebo ignition?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress

As the title mention, I am working on a gazebo project on gazebo classic. And I made the robot model using urdf and using roslaunch to launch the project. However one of the plugins I planned to use([segmentation cam](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/6.0/segmentationcamera_igngazebo.html)) seems to only work in ignition gazebo. What can I do to launch it in ignition gazebo? Or if there's a way to use segmentation cam in gazebo classic would be appreciated either.

These are the environments I'm using:

> Ubuntu 20.04
> Gazebo version 11.14.0. 
>  Gazebo Fortress 
>  ROS 1

My [project](https://github.com/brian2lee/forklift_test) in case you want to check.